# How can I return the original names of objects in a list?

Tags: r

I've created a named list of previously generated plots and matrices, and I'd like to return the original names of those elements.

```
mylist <- list(FirstPlot=myplot1, FirstMatrix=mymatrix1, SecondPlot=myplot2)
```

`names(mylist)` returns
`[1] "FirstPlot" "FirstMatrix" "SecondPlot"`

but I want to return `[1] "myplot1" "mymatrix1" "myplot2"`

I feel like there must be an easy way to do this but I can't find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any objections to naming as desired when creating the list?

Comment: When you name the objects in your list, you are actually replacing the original object names.  If you print mylist you will see that each object is headed by the new name.  It's original name is gone.

Comment: @Wimpel Do you mean `mylist <- list(myplot1=myplot1, ...`? That would have been possible but I've named the elements in the list for one purpose and now I want the original names for something else. Also, I didn't actually create the list in one go: I added and named objects as I generated them, and going back through the code will be tedious.

Comment: @SteveM So would there be a way to do this with a nameless list e.g. `mylist2 <- c(myplot1, mymatrix1, myplot2)`? In that case, `names(list)` returns `NULL`. Does creating the list always lose the original names?

Comment: @Roland Thanks but I want to return the names from `mylist` not from the original objects.

Comment: BTW, a better check to printing an object that I suggested is printing its structure, `str(mylist)`.  That will show you all of the object's meta-data.

Comment: It's mysterious why you would need this.

Answer (score 5):

In case you have **not changed** the content of the `list` and also not the originals you can try to find the original names by its address.

```
df1 <- data.frame(1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(2:7)
df3 <- data.frame(8:11)

mylist <- list(FirstPlot=df1, FirstMatrix=df2, SecondPlot=df3)

x <- sapply(ls(), function(x) tracemem(get(x)))
y <- sapply(mylist, tracemem)
cbind(names(y), names(x)[match(y, x)])
#     [,1]          [,2] 
#[1,] "FirstPlot"   "df1"
#[2,] "FirstMatrix" "df2"
#[3,] "SecondPlot"  "df3"
```

Comment: Never thought of this approach, very cool.. one day I will need this :)

Comment: I feel like this is a case, where it would be better to extract this information from the script (or history).

Comment: Thanks @GKi. This doesn't work for me - `x <- sapply(ls(), function(x) tracemem(get(x)))` gives `Error in tracemem(get(x)) : argument must not be a function` - but in any case, if this is the only way to do it I think I'm barking up the wrong tree and @Roland is right. The lesson I'm taking away is that the original names are not stored in the list.

Comment: @ParAtEPt maybe `x <- sapply(ls(), function(x) if(is.function(x)) NA else tracemem(get(x)))` will work. Yes, the original names are currently not stored in the list. One way is, as @Roland wrote already, to use your script or history.