# How to obtain model name from the list?

Tags: r, list, names

Let's consider two models and list created by those:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- runif(100)
z <- rexp(100)
model_1 <- lm(y ~ x)
model_2 <- lm(y ~ z)

model_list <- list(model_1, model_2)
```

How from the `model_list` I can obtain names of the models within it ? i.e. to somehow output `"model_1"`, `"model_2"`. I tried to use `substitute(model_list[[1]])` but it doesn't solve the issue. DO you know how it can be obtained ?

**EDIT**

I tried to use the code proposed in the comments:

```
x <- sapply(ls(), function(x) if(is.function(x)) NA else tracemem(get(x)))
```

But I got error:

```
Error in tracemem(get(x)) : argument must not be a function
```

Do you know how it can be solved ?

**EDIT 2**

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rnorm(100)
k <- runif(100)
z <- rexp(100)
model_1 <- lm(y ~ k)
model_2 <- lm(y ~ z)
model_list <- list(model_1, model_2)



x <- sapply(ls(), function(x) if(is.function(x)) NA else tracemem(get(x)))

Error in tracemem(get(x)) : argument must not be a function
```

Could you please see if it works for you ?

Comment: Try: `mget(c("model_1", "model_2"))` instead of `list(model_1, model_2)`.

Comment: I would rather prefer to do not change definition of model_list in solution

Comment: Then have a look at [How can I return the original names of objects in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62895397/10488504).

Comment: Hey I updated my question: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Try `names(sapply(ls(), function(x) if(is.function(x)) NA else tracemem(get(x))))[1:2]`

Comment: Got exactly the same error

Comment: It depends on what is in your .GlobalEnv which is what `ls()` will yield. Try a fresh R session.

Comment: Have a look to the comments in the link. There I wrote to use `sapply(ls(), function(x) if(is.function(x)) NA else tracemem(get(x)))` in this case.

Comment: Then I get same error: 

Error in tracemem(get(x)) : argument must not be a function

Comment: I updated my question by exact code that I'm using. Could you please have a look at this and see if it's compatible with your thinking ?

Comment: What R version are you using? Additional try to start r in *vanilla* mode `R --vanilla`.

Comment: I'm using R 3.6.3

Comment: Maybe make an update. I get on `4.0.4` no error message.